# react-native and react-navigation Unable to pass a function as a param to the next screen in NavigationOptions

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

i am able to to pass a function to the next screen as a param in the render function as you can see the codes below

```
render(){
      return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.titlewrapper}>

        <Text style={styles.titleinfo}><Icon name="add-circle" style={{color:"#039BE5"}}/> Customize your own feed </Text>
        </View>
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=> requestAnimationFrame(()=>{ this.props.navigation.navigate('topic', {onNavigateBack: this.handleOnNavigateBack.bind(this)
}) }) }
          >
           <View style={styles.buttoncontainer}>
             <Text style={styles.buttontext}>Get started</Text>
             </View>
          </TouchableOpacity>
       </View>

      );
    }
```

as you can see i can pass the function "handleOnNavigateBack" as onNavigateBack param to topic screen and its working but i can't achieve this in NavigationOptions as you can see it below

```
 static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
      const { params = {} } = navigation.state;
      return{
        headerStyle:{
            elevation:0 
           },
        headerTitle:  (
          <Image style={{ height: responsiveHeight(6), width: responsiveWidth(30), alignSelf:'center' }} source={require('../images/logo-header2.png')}/>
      ),
        headerLeft: <TouchableOpacity  onPress={ () => navigation.navigate('DrawerOpen')  } ><Icon name="menu" style={{paddingLeft:15 }} size={35}/></TouchableOpacity>,
        headerRight: <TouchableOpacity  onPress={ () => navigation.navigate('topic', {
          onNavigateBack: this.handleOnNavigateBack.bind(this)  }) }><Icon name="create" style={{paddingRight:15 }} size={35}/></TouchableOpacity>,

        } 
      };
```

i have tried every thing but it seems not to work, any help will be appreciated !

software | version

react-navigation | 1.0.0-beta.19

react-native | 0.49.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because that 'this' of `onNavigateBack: this.handleOnNavigateBack.bind(this)` in second code is not pointing your component like you did at first code.(since `navigationOptions` is a static)

To archive what you want, you should pass your function to navigation's param from your component first. Then, you call it in NavigationOption by using params.

Comment: @Broght Lee i can not get it but i tried it                                                                   this.props.navigation.setParams({ handleOnNavigateBack:this.handleOnNavigateBack})  i put  this code in componentDidMount  or componentWillMountare causing warning of can not mount the unmounted state

Comment: @dannykush Hm.. you should be able to `this.props.navigation.setParams.()` on componentDidMount or componentWillMount. Because that's what I'm doing all the time. Something is wrong...

Comment: Then you can call it in your headerRight of navigationOptions like `navigation.state.params.handleOnNavigateBack()`. This is what I tried to explain in the answer. Something is wrong..

Comment: thank you for your helpful feedback but thats exactly what i did and it was showing me errors so i used this  in componentDidMount
    <!-- language: lang-js -->    handleOnNavigateBack = this.handleOnNavigateBack.bind(this) and i was able to access it by handleOnNavigateBack  and its working as charm, am going to mark your answer as collect

Comment: hm.. I'm sorry about that. I use that technic in many places. Please check if any other thing goes wrong. @dannykush

Comment: thank you for your helpful feedback but thats exactly what i did and it was showing me errors so i used this  in componentDidMount
       `handleOnNavigateBack = this.handleOnNavigateBack.bind(this)`  and i was able to access it by `handleOnNavigateBack`  and its working as charm, am going to mark your answer as collect

Comment: Oh, I didn't see your comment carefully. I'm glad it goes well :)

Comment: Please see my recently posted question. I am trying to do something similar but am getting errors when I try to implement.